how to see pacbio reads in IGV
This question has also been asked on Biostars
I recently used pbmm2 to align my reads to the reference genome, when I specified  --sort option it is generated a file with extension bam.bai. Afterwards, an index with extension .bam.pbi was generated with pbindex. IGV could not open .bam.pbi, so I tried with bam.bai. The first time I could see the mapping, but I have tried the same steps as the first time and I cannot see the coverage of the reads.

What file did you open? Have you tried opening the .bam file?

You should just open the bam file, not one of the index files.
